# jquery for loop to create multiple buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, pagination

I need to create a set amount of buttons using jquery.  I've tried a `for` loop and a `while` loop but this isn't working.

I'm storing the amount of pages I need in a variable 'pages', which when using `console.log(pages)` correctly shows how many buttons I require yet I still can't get the loop to work.

```
while (i <= pages) {
    pageButtons.append('<input type="button" id="button'+i+'" value="Random'+i+'"/>');
    i = i + 1;
}
```

I currently have the above code..

Comment: Hi, can you please post the entire relevant piece of HTML and JavaScript? If `pageButtons` is not a jQuery object, it will not work.

Comment: You should specify your problem clearly with proper code.

Comment: what is `pageButtons`?

Comment: Here you go: https://jsfiddle.net/x4p9n09w/

Answer (score 0):

What is `pageButtons` assigned to? If you contain all of the buttons in a div, this will work

```js
var pages = 5;
var pageButtons = $('#pageButtons');
for (var i = 0; i < pages; i++) {
  pageButtons.append('<input type="button" id="button' + i + '" value="Random' + i + '"/>');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="pageButtons">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You would want to do something like this:

```
var pages = 5;
for (var i = 0; i <= pages; i++) {
  $('#buttons').append('<input type="button" id="button' + i + '"value="Random' + i + '"/>');
}
```

http:////jsfiddle.net/clccmh/x545y8re/